# java,матрицы,помогите

Tags: java

Уже который час пытаюсь понять,не могу найти подвох

```
class Matrix{
    private static int size;
    private static long[][] mat;
    Matrix(int n)//создается единичная матрица
    {
    size = n;
    mat = new long[size][size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            if(i == j)
                mat[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    }
   public static void setElement(int row, int column, int element)//вставляем элемент
   {
    mat[row][column] = element;
   }
}

    class Main{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Matrix m = new Matrix(5);
        Matrix n = new Matrix(5);

        System.out.println("\nMatrix M:\n" + m);//до
        System.out.println("\nMatrix N:\n" + n);
        m.setElement(0, 2, 7);
        System.out.println("\nMatrix:\n" + m);//после 
        System.out.println("\nMatrix:\n" + n);
}
```

почему размещая элемент в матрицу m(в данном случчае 7),она автоматом меняется и в матрице n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что mat у вас общая переменная для обеих матриц. Как я понимаю статическая.

Comment: обеих.... ибо матрицы не мужики

Comment: Нет. Просто сделайте класс матрицы, в котором будет массив инициализируемый в конструкторе и нужные методы доступа и изменения. Ни каких статических методов и переменных не надо.

Comment: извините,не до конца дописал.Сейчас вроде бы все как надо,но вопрос еще открытый

Comment: Я же сказал, что ни каких статических переменых и методов не надо.

Comment: @АлександрМартынцев,спасибо большое)а как это связано со static в 2 словах если можно)?

Comment: Если вы объявляет переменную как static, то это означает, что она будет иметь ссылку на объект единую для всех экземпляров данного класса. Т.е. в вашем случае сколько бы вы раз не создавали объект матрицы, то все равно массив указывал бы во всех них на одну и туже область памяти.

Comment: Всё, что static, не имеет отношения к объекту - эти свойства относятся к классу, то есть общие для всех объектов.

Comment: Теперь все встало на свои места,еще раз спасибо!